# Why I can't use StringEntity when I use Android API 23

Tags: android

```
client.post(AppConfig.getApplicationContext(),
                  HttpUrls.getUrl()
                + urlroot, new StringEntity(jsonData, "UTF-8"),
                "application/json", handler);
```

I use StringEntity as HttpEntity when I post a request by XHttpClient in Android API 21, but when I use Android API 23, I cannot use it again. I think there should be a class in API 23 which equivalent to the class StringEntity in API 21, so which class can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Support for Apache HTTP Client has been removed from Android 6.0. Check [Android 6.0 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html).

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
> useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> }
> ```